# Run a function when new image is uploaded in media library

Tags: plugin-development, attachments, media-library

I want to run a function of my plugin that I am developing when ever user upload a new image to the library.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`wp_handle_upload_prefilter`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter) filter hook and it will be called when user will upload the file from admin side.

Or

You can use the [`wp_handle_upload`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_handle_upload-7/) filter hook for the uploaded file.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever an image is uploaded to the library, the [`add_attachment`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_attachment/) hook is called, which is internally called by `wp_insert_attachment();`. This hook accepts the created attachment's ID.

So, this is how you can hook into the uploaded attachment:

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'my_function' );
function my_function( $attachment_id ){
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

The hook is located at `wp-includes/post.php`, if you need to dig some more information since the documentations are not really complete about this.

Comment: can I run js function in it?

Comment: add_action( 'add_attachment', 'auto_on_upload' );
      function auto_on_upload( $attachment_id )
      {
          ?>
          <script>
          alert("hello");
          </script>
          <?php
      }

Comment: When I do this it broke the uploader and when I upload any image it shows me An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

Comment: oh ok let me do it

Comment: its not working can you help me in that also :D

Comment: Hey, is there any function which calls after images is uploaded.

Comment: The action hook I posted it triggered, but it's on the server side. If you need to hook into a front-side upload, you can use a JavaScript event listener for file upload. Unfortunately that case is not a WordPress related question, but you can find a lot of articles about it by searching.